# Facebook integration with android application for wall post?

Tags: android, facebook

i made an app on which there is share button, i want when users click on that button then his/her Facebook wall is updated with my customized message. I have done this by using  Facebook integration and app-id that is in my Facebook account but it update only my wall not on other walls.

Comment: fyi: you are not allowed to prefill the message, it always has to be 100% user generated.

Comment: that being said, how exactly do you update your wall? with /me/feed posting?